# Statistical test: which party do most of the voters belong to?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation

I am looking for a statistical test able to explain the results I have found.

I have the following fields (political categories):

```
Right
Center
Left
```

I would like to see which category is mostly associated with people who voted.
My dataset is

```
Voted? Political Category
1            Right
0            Left
1            Center
1            Right
1            Right
1            Right
```

1 means that a person voted.
Most people are from Right wing. I would like to justify this statistically.
Do you know which test would be useful (e.g., correlation, chi squared, ... ) ?
Currently I have a bar chart that shows the distribution of people who voted/not voted by Political category.
I have

```
(1, Right) : 1500 people
(0, Right) : 202 people
(1, Left): 826 people
(0, Left): 652 people
(1, Center): 431 people
(0, Center): 542 people
```

Feel free to change the tags appropriately, if you need.

Comment: Could you describe your results?  That should be simple enough to be able to include it in the post.

Comment: Hi whuber. I added more information on the distribution of data. I have plotted only the distribution of voted/non-voted people by category. I would need to understand if a test can give more strength to the discussion on the results (based on the number of people who voted/non voted per category)

Comment: What you're looking for is a chi-squared test of independence. You want to see if political party is independent of voting status or if they are somehow related. You can check out this page I found, or just google chi-squared test of independence. https://www.jmp.com/en_ch/statistics-knowledge-portal/chi-square-test/chi-square-test-of-independence.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data below goes into a table `TBL`.

```
(1, Right) : 1500 people
(0, Right) : 202 people
(1, Left): 826 people
(0, Left): 652 people
(1, Center): 431 people
(0, Center): 542 people
```

In R, as shown
below, we use Rows `yes` and `no` for voted or not, and columns R, L, and C for political views.

```
yes = c(1500, 826, 431)
no  = c(212, 652, 542)
TBL = rbind(yes, no);  TBL

    [,1] [,2] [,3]
yes 1500  826  431
no   212  652  542
```

With P-value near $0$ the chi-squared test
strongly rejects the null hypothesis that the voting and political categories are independent.

```
chisq.test(TBL, cor=F)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  TBL
X-squared = 630.08, df = 2, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

The roughly equivalent `prop.test` gives about
the same P-value as `chisq.test` (depending partly on whether
a continuity correction is used). However, this
test displays the proportions of those voting
in each political category.

```
tot = yes + no
prop.test(yes, tot, cor=F)

    3-sample test for equality of proportions
    without continuity correction

data:  yes out of tot
X-squared = 630.08, df = 2, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2    prop 3 
0.8761682 0.5588633 0.4429599
```

The pattern is pretty clear. However, with
appropriate adjustments to avoid 'false discovery'
by multiple analyses of the same data (perhaps
consider the Bonferroni method), *post hoc* tests
could be done to see whether proportions for L and C are statistically independent, and similarly for R and L (perhaps testing both at the 1% level).